# Can you say “go picnic” in stead of “go on a picnic”?

Tags: grammar

Can you say “Will you go picnic tomorrow?” In stead of “Will you go on a picnic tomorrow?”

Comment: Do you want to ask if the person will go for a picnic tomorrow *with you*, or if he/she will go to a picnic tomorrow *(with/ without you)*?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [**picnic**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/picnic) is both a noun and a verb:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   *noun, often attributive*
>   **1** : an excursion or outing with food usually provided by members of the group and eaten in the open
>   *verb*
>   : to go on a picnic : eat in picnic fashion

In short, both of these are fine:

> I am going to go on *a picnic*. [noun]
>   I am going to go *picnic*. [verb]

The verb sense of the word has variations:

> I am going to go *picknicking*.
>   I am going to *picnic*.
>   I *picnicked* yesterday.

---

Having said that, its use as a noun is more common than its use as a verb.

Also, I would guess that, when it comes to its use as a verb, *go picnicking* is the more common variation.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* say "Will you go picnic tomorrow," since 'picnic' can act as a noun or a verb. But the most common use is as a noun, so it may sound odd to some people at first. It sounds as though a word is missing, since most people would say, "Will you go on ***on a*** picnic tomorrow?"

In addition, 'will' has various meanings depending on context, etc. 'Will you' is used to form a request: "Will you hand me the wrench?" But it is more imperative, which is to say, it makes the request sound important, even vitally important.

If this is a polite request, expressing your desire to picnic with someone, 'would,' is a better choice to form that polite request: "Would you go picnic tomorrow?" But this will also sound odd to most native speakers - it still sounds like a word is missing,

One way to clarify would be to use the infinitive of 'like' to enquire about their willingness to join you: "Would you like to go picnic tomorrow?" If what you want is to let someone know what you desire (I would like to picnic with you), 'would like' is a good choice to express preferences.

Here are some links:

[Writing Explained: Will vs Would](https://writingexplained.org/will-vs-would-difference)

[Grammer.com: When to Use Would instead of Will](https://www.grammar.com/when_to_use_%E2%80%9Cwould%E2%80%9D_instead_of_%E2%80%9Cwill%E2%80%9D)

[Learn English - Will and Would](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/will-and-would)

Answer (score 0):

In

> Will you go picnic tomorrow?

Since go and picnic are both verbs, it will be better to rephrase the question as

> Will you picnic (with me) tomorrow?

Moreover, is there any specific reason you wrote

> Will you go ***on*** a picnic tomorrow?

When you could have also said

> Will you go ***for*** a picnic tomorrow?
>
> Will you go ***to*** a picnic tomorrow?